# How to query on joined table attribute in sqlachemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using sql alchemy in my project.

I have one problem when two or more tables are joined or have foreign key relation then i am unable to query on joined tables attribute in where condition.

Eg. I have notice table and a user table user.id is foreign key of notice.sender
now I want to search notice by user.name

1. notice table:[id, sender(FK user.id), receiver(FK user.id), subject, message, status]
2. user table: [id, name, email, address, status]

Join in notice model:

```
 sender_user = relationship('User', primaryjoin='Notice.sender==user.id', backref=backref("sender_user"))
 receiver_user = relationship('User', primaryjoin='Notice.receiver==user.id', backref=backref("receiver_user"))
```

SQL alchemy filter query:

```
  user_name='john'

  notice=db_session.query(Notice) 
  notice = notice.filter(Notice.sender_user.name == user_name)
```

Following query doesn't works:

```
  notice=db_session.query(Notice) 
  notice = notice.filter(Notice.user.name == user_name)
```

Please help!

Comment: In the second query, do you mean `notice.sender.name`?

Comment: @jadkik94 For second query error is:  Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'name'

Comment: @jadkik94 same error for first query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to acquire a session object, then do:

```
query = session.query(Notice).filter(Notice.sender_user.name == user_name)
results = query.all()
```

If that does not work (you don't get the results you expect), try doing this:

```
session.query(Notice, User.name).filter((Notice.sender_user.id == User.id) & (User.name == user_name))
results = query.all()
```

I suppose you also have a field called `sender` which is the id of the user. Then, this should also work:

```
session.query(Notice, User.name).filter((Notice.sender == User.id) & (User.name == user_name))
```

Retry all of them, I made some small modifications. (you can see them in revision history). It would be weird if they don't work... (If they don't, try posting the question on the [SQLAlchemy mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/sqlalchemy))

Comment: Hi, I missed one line in question, code update regarding what is notice

Comment: Ok. It's weird, it should have worked... See my updated answer for other options.